# Using class function on objects stored in List, accessed through iterator

Tags: c++, class, function, iterator

I'm trying to print the names of some instances of `Player`, which is stored in a `List<Player>` players. What should I replace "Plop!" with to get this to work?

```
   list<Player>::iterator it;
   for(it=players.begin(); it != players.end(); ++it) cout << "Plop!" << " ";
   cout << endl;
```

I have tried

```
*it.getName();
*it->getName();
```

I have a feeling that the iterator should be handled differently than if it would be a normal pointer. Or perhaps the iterator `*it` does not contain the Player object at all?

Comment: As an alternative solution, consider implementing `operator<<` for Player class. Either as an overload or a friend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be;

```
(*it).getName()
```

the . operator binds harder than *, which makes the compilation fail otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
it->getName();
```

as long as `Player` has this method...

Answer (score 0):

you need to dereference the iterator, as you're doing

```
*it
```

but the dereferencing drops to the left, if you know what i mean :) so you need to keep it in place with some parenthesis:

```
(*it).getName();
```

and don't forget the curly braces in the for loop!